# Split salary range

Tags: r, regex, strsplit

I am trying to split the first column range into two separate columns as so

[image]

I have tried the following code:

```
testDF$IncomeLowerRange <- strsplit(gsub("[^-]+-", "", testDF$IncomeRange), ";")[1]
testDF$IncomeUpperRange <- strsplit(gsub("[^-]+-", "", testDF$IncomeRange), ";")[2]
```

Comment: What is the logic by which `$100,000+` ends up having an upper range of `250,000` ?

Comment: No specific logic, there is just no range assigned to anyone with a salary of $100,000+.

Comment: Paste the input as text please. `dput(head(testDF))`

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to relevel the first factor. `testDF$IncomeLowerRange<-factor(testDF$IncomeRange,labels =c(25000,50000,....))`

Comment: @OmegaSupreme: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is a one-liner for this as you need to extract some of the data, replace fully or partially in other cases.

I suggest using a simple logic for this:

```
> test <- c("$25,000-49,000","Not displayed", "$100,000+")
> df <- data.frame(test)
> df$col1 <- sub("^\\$?([0-9,]+).*", "\\1", df$test)
> df$col1[df$col1=="Not displayed"] <- "NA"
> df$col2 <- sub("^[^-]+-(.*)", "\\1", df$test)
> df$col2[df$col2=="Not displayed"] <- "NA"
> df$col2[df$col2=="$100,000+"] <- "250,000"
> 
> df
            test    col1    col2
1 $25,000-49,000  25,000  49,000
2  Not displayed      NA      NA
3      $100,000+ 100,000 250,000
```

where `col1` will be your `IncomeLowerRange` and `col2` will be your `IncomeUpperRange`.

The `^\\$?([0-9,]+).*` regex is used to extract the first number from a range, and also `100,000` into the first column (`^` matches the start of string, `\$?` matches 1 or 0 `$` symbols, `([0-9,]+)` captures digits and commas into Group 1 that is kept, and the rest (also, all after the number - `.*`) is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the number of levels is limited (as in your example) a very easy solution might be the following

```
IncomeRange <- c("$25,000-49,000","$50,000-74,999",
          "Not displayed","$25,000-49,000", "$100,000+",
          "$100,000+","$75,000-99,999")
df <- data.frame(IncomeRange)

# IncomeRange only has 5 levels
levels(df$IncomeRange)
[1] "$100,000+"      "$25,000-49,000" "$50,000-74,999"
[4] "$75,000-99,999" "Not displayed" 

df$IncomeLowerRange<-factor(df$IncomeRange,
                                labels =c(100000,25000,50000,75000,NA))
df$IncomeUpperRange<-factor(df$IncomeRange,
                            labels =c(250000,49000,74999,99999,NA))
```

Output

```
     IncomeRange IncomeLowerRange IncomeUpperRange
1 $25,000-49,000            25000            49000
2 $50,000-74,999            50000            74999
3  Not displayed             <NA>             <NA>
4 $25,000-49,000            25000            49000
5      $100,000+            1e+05           250000
6      $100,000+            1e+05           250000
7 $75,000-99,999            75000            99999
```